# DatePicker enter key event control

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using enter key to move focus within the page.I have used datepicker hide and show but when I press enter key datepicker is shown once and then hide.It is due to the show event of datepicker is called twice.Please let me know how to stop the event of enter key which fires to show datepicker.I have also used event.prevenDefault();.I will be highly thankful to you.I am using jquery-1.5.2.min.js of struts jquery.

Comment: What library are you using? Can you provide an example that shows the issue at hand?

Comment: can you post your code? Need to see, how you are using it.

Comment: Hi, Dom I am using strus jquery 1.5.2 .Please help me out.